# Как полностью ограничить ввод текста в ячейку DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Как полностью ограничить ввод текста в ячейку DataGridView.

Answer (score 2):

Cделайте ее доступной только для чтения:

```
dataGridView1[columnIndex, rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Не подойдет. Дело в том что при двойном клике у меня будет в этой ячейке combobox.

Comment: @VictorSayapov, при двойном клике по этой ячейке, что должно произойти: ничего или `combobox` появиться?

Comment: @VictorSayapov, даже, если появляется `combobox`, ячейка будет доступна только для чтения